# How to configure home router from terminal?

Tags: router

I want handle options that are provided by TP-LINK router, like `MAC filtering`, `wireless stats`, `forwarding` and other features from my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Xou can do this by using `links2` which is a pure text based browser for terminal.

To install `links2`:

```
sudo apt-get install links2
```

Then you can call your router by its normal adress he has in the network example (taken from my network):

```
links2 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: This does not work. The result of opening the router's web interface with links2 is `Unsupported browser!`